# Pyspark crashing for large datasets

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning pyspark but came across this error. I have been stuck at this for a few hours now. I have seen many questions on StackOverflow but most of them either increase the driver memory or executor memory. I also tried [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12261?focusedCommentId=15144734&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15144734) but doesn't seem to get it working. Anybody here if has experienced such an error, your help is much appreciated.

The same code is working if I have a smaller dataset, but when I use a large dataset this error comes up again.

My laptop configurations:

---

```
Windows 10 home
Pyspark 2.4+
Java 8 
python 3.5 and pypy
RAM: 16GB
```

spark-defaults.conf

---

```
spark.master                     local[*]
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    file:///C:/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-events
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///C:/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-events
spark.driver.memory              7g
spark.broadcast.compress         true
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout       10000000
spark.network.timeout            10000000
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10000000
```

Code:

---

```
    import sys
    assert sys.version_info >= (3, 5) # make sure we have Python 3.5+
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions, types, DataFrameReader
    
    @functions.udf(returnType=types.StringType())
    def path_to_hour(path):
        splitted = path.split("/")
        hour = splitted[-1][11:22]
        return hour
    
    
    def main(inputs, output):
        schema = "language STRING, title STRING, views INT, bytes INT"
    
        df = spark.read.csv(path=inputs, schema=schema, sep=" ", header=False).withColumn('filename', functions.input_file_name())
        df_new = df.withColumn('hour', path_to_hour(df['filename'])).drop('filename')
    
        en_df = df_new.filter(df_new['language'] == 'en')
        title_df = en_df.filter(en_df['title'] != 'Main_Page')
        df_2 = title_df.filter(title_df['title'].startswith('Special:') == False)
        print(df_2.show(10))
        data_new_1 = df_2.alias('data_new_1')
    
        data = df_2.groupBy(['hour']).agg(functions.max("views").alias('max_views'))
        print(data.show(10))
        data_new_2 = data.alias('data_new_2')
    
        new_data = data_new_1.join(functions.broadcast(data_new_2), (functions.col("data_new_1.hour") == functions.col("data_new_2.hour")) &
                                   (functions.col("data_new_1.views") == functions.col("data_new_2.max_views")))
        always = new_data.select("data_new_1.hour", "data_new_1.title", "data_new_2.max_views")
        sorted_df = always.sort("hour")
        print(sorted_df.show())
        sorted_df.coalesce(1).write.json(output, mode='overwrite')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        inputs = sys.argv[1]
        output = sys.argv[2]
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('wikipedia popular').getOrCreate()
        assert spark.version >= '2.4' # make sure we have Spark 2.4+
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')
        sc = spark.sparkContext
        start_time = timer()
        # for i in range(5):
        main(inputs, output)
        print("Average Execution Time: {}".format(timer() - start_time))
```

Error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
20/10/12 19:22:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 65)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 65, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

20/10/12 19:22:02 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 4 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 415, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 402, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 724, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 72, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 62, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 70, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 71, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
20/10/12 19:22:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 68, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/akash/Downloads/SFU/Semester_1/cmpt_732/a5/./wikipedia_popular_df.py", line 47, in <module>
    main(inputs, output)
  File "C:/Users/akash/Downloads/SFU/Semester_1/cmpt_732/a5/./wikipedia_popular_df.py", line 34, in main
    print(sorted_df.show())
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 381, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o101.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenInner(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:598)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 65, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1925)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1913)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1912)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1912)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2146)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2095)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2084)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:759)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectIterator(SparkPlan.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting the answer as I found .drop() is not valid here.

```
df_new = df.withColumn('hour', path_to_hour(df['filename'])).drop('filename')
```

instead use this:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('hour', path_to_hour(df['filename']))
```

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is your culprit: `sorted_df.coalesce(1).write.json(output, mode='overwrite')` . You have to understand repercussions that arise when repartitioning or coalescing to a single partition. Now, all your data will have to be transferred to a single worker in order to write it to a single file. You could try it with `repartition(1)` instead of `coalesce(1)`. Plus, not sure why you need `print(sorted_df.show())`.

Comment: I tried it without coalesce and repartition, it still gives the same error. It is working fine with a small dataset. size of bigger data is .97GB and smaller is 1.45MB.

Comment: you are running a memory intensive job (lot of dfs in there) on a local machine, there is not much of parallelization there. Run it in AWS Glue with 10 DPU's and you wont have issues. Maybe covert your dateset to parquet,  it will be ~1/10th of the size.

Comment: That's correct, on the cluster it is working fine. Even increasing the size of driver memory to 7gb not able to run it in local mode. Can you elaborate on this? By parallelization you mean the number of partitions or cores in my pc?

Comment: in your case number of cores, basically how work gets split up

Comment: I think coalesce should be used here, as it is a narrow transformation whereas repartition is a wide transformation.